# The dependency RabbitMQ.Client 3.6.2 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Tags: visual-studio, rabbitmq, nuget-package, asp.net-core-1.0

I have create a project using the latest version of asp .net core and I want to add a reference to RabbitMQ.  I have tried the nuget package RabbitMQ.Client v3.6.2 however it brings up this error.  My version of Visual Studio 2015 is totally up-to-date.

Is there a way to ignore the version or is it possible to build a new version of RabbitMQ.Client by getting the code from github?